# How to put a div within an svg object

Tags: r, svg, shiny, shinyapps

I want to place a `div` within an `svg` object in my `Shiny app` as below -

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(id = "height: 255px; width: 205px", 
                                tag("svg", 
                                    list('viewBox' = "0 0 500 150",
                                            'preserveAspectRatio' = "none",
                                            'style' = "height: 100%; width: 100%;  filter: drop-shadow( 12px 12px 7px #00acd6 );",
                                            tag("path", list('d' = "M0.28,-0.48 C178.61,30.09 229.40,133.70 501.41,129.77 L500.00,0.00 L0.28,-1.47 Z",
                                                                'style' = "stroke: #00acd6;  stroke-width: 1px; fill: rgba(0,172,214, .01);"
                                                            )),
                                            div(style = "height: 160px; width: 160px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);", HTML("AAA"))))

                            )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

The reason for putting the 2nd `div` within the `svg` is that 2nd `div` should always be placed within the `svg` even when resizing the parent window. If the parent window becomes too small then the `svg` should hide the overflown portion of the 2nd `div`.

**Based on *Robert Longson's* suggestion I introduced `foreignObject` as below -**

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(id = "height: 255px; width: 205px", 
                                tag("svg", 
                                    list('viewBox' = "0 0 500 150",
                                            'preserveAspectRatio' = "none",
                                            'style' = "height: 100%; width: 100%;  filter: drop-shadow( 12px 12px 7px #00acd6 ); overflow: hidden;",
                                            tag("path", list('d' = "M0.28,-0.48 C178.61,30.09 229.40,133.70 501.41,129.77 L500.00,0.00 L0.28,-1.47 Z",
                                                                'style' = "stroke: #00acd6;  stroke-width: 1px; fill: rgba(0,172,214, .01);"
                                                            )),
                                            tag("foreignObject",
                                                list(x = "0", y = "0",
                                                      width = "100%", height = "50%",
                                                      div(style = "height: 160px; width: 200px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
                                                                    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;", HTML("AAA"))
                                                    ))


                                          ))

                            )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

Now, with that I see shadow on every element within the `foreignObject`. Is there any way to r**emove shadow from those elements** and only keep it with outer boundary?

Any pointer how to achieve this will be highly helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: The parent of the div must be a foreignObject element.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. Is there any way to remove shadow from the elements within foreignObject?

Comment: Sure, remove the drop-shadow style.

Comment: Shadow should remain in the outer line, not with elements inside

Comment: Then move it to where you want it to apply or use a CSS selector to apply it only to the elements you want.

Comment: Have put filter: none;  in the styling of 2nd div, but it is not disappearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend—depending on the end goal of your app of course— using svg elements for this. The elements `<rect>` and `<text>` will help with this as you can specify the coordinates and other useful attributes.

Adding shadows to svg elements works a bit differently than in css. Instead, use the svg element `<filter>` and `<feDropShadow>` for this. Filters will need to be defined in the `<defs>` element. You can use the `tag(...)` function to define these elements, but it may be easier to wrap it all in the `HTML()` function.

```r
# using html
HTML('
    <defs>
        <filter id="shadow">
            <feDropShadow dx="0.2" dy="0.6" stdDeviation="0.8"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
')

# using tag
tag(
    "defs",
    list(
        tag(
            "filter",
            list(
                "id" = "shadow",
                tag(
                    "feDropShadow",
                    list(
                        "dx" = "0.2",
                        "dy" = "0.6",
                        "stdDeviation" = "0.8"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Then, add the shadow to the appropriate element(s) using `style = "filter: url(#shadow);` (or use whatever id you set).

```r
# add to path
tag(
    "path",
    list(
        d = "...",
        style = "filter: url(#shadow);"
        ...
    )
)
```

Here's the full example using pure svg elements.

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    div(
        id = "height: 255px; width: 205px", 
        tag(
            "svg", 
            list(
                'viewBox' = "0 0 500 150",
                'preserveAspectRatio' = "none",
                'style' = "height: 100%; width: 100%;",
                tag(
                    "defs",
                    list(
                        tag(
                            "filter",
                            list(
                                "id" = "shadow",
                                tag(
                                    "feDropShadow",
                                    list(
                                        "dx" = "0.2",
                                        "dy" = "0.6",
                                        "stdDeviation" = "0.8"
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                HTML('
                    <defs>
                    <filter id="shadow">
                        <feDropShadow dx="0.2" dy="0.6" stdDeviation="0.8"/>
                    </filter>
                    </defs>
                '),
                tag(
                    "path", 
                    list(
                        'd' = "M0.28,-0.48 C178.61,30.09 229.40,133.70 501.41,129.77 L500.00,0.00 L0.28,-1.47 Z",
                        'style' = "stroke: #00acd6;  stroke-width: 1px; fill: rgba(0,172,214, .01); filter: url(#shadow)"
                    )
                ),
                tag(
                    "rect",
                    list(
                        "width" = "100px",
                        "height" = "100px",
                        "x" = "0",
                        "y" = "50",
                        "fill"  = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
                    )
                ),
                tag(
                    "text",
                    list(
                        "x" = "5",
                        "y" = "70",
                        "AAA"
                    )
                )
            )
        )

    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you need the `div`, then adapt the `filter` for your application. That should fix the shadows issue.

Hope that helps! Let me know if you have any questions. For more information checkout the following resources.

- Mozilla's FeDropShadow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feDropShadow

Comment: That is really insighful answer. Thanks for this detailing.